# How to mock another static method in the same class which is being tested?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I am writing JUnit Test case with Mockito for a class which has two methods methodA,methodB. I would like to mock the call to the methodA from methodB in my test case.Some one help me.pls

Here is the class:

```
public Class Test{
    public static List<Object> methodA() {
        ...
        return list;    
    }

    public static List<Object> methodB() {
        ...
        list = methodA();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use "when" to mock the method call

Comment: First of all... Why? Why is this static method there? Think about it. Again. Again. If you need to mock this static method, it sounds like this static method is actually a dependency and should go into it's own class (with non-static methods), so that it could be mocked easily. Having to mock a static method is a code smell (which means that it could be an indication that the code in question is bad).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use PowerMockito to mock the static method.

Example:

```
package unitest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(unitest.Test.class)
public class TestTest {

    @Test
    public void testMethodB() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(unitest.Test.class);
        PowerMockito.when(unitest.Test.methodA()).thenReturn(new ArrayList());
        List b = unitest.Test.methodB();
        org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(b);
    }

}
```